# Mapping the value of an input to a complex structure

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's imagine I have this following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Data{
    public string Prop1 { get; set;}
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm building a custom server control, that will store its value into a `input type=hidden` field, that contains a json serialized version of this class (used by some kind of javascript on the client side). This value may be modified by the javascript code and should always be accurate on both client and server side.

Expected Html output is, at first launch :

```
<input type="hidden" value="{ Prop1:'zzz', Prop2: 42 }" />
```

In order to make it simple to use for developers, I want to publish one property of this type in my server control, that can be written directly, including the nested properties :

```
public class MyControl : WebControl {

    public Data Data {
        get; // correct implementation to be found
    }

}

// somewhere else

void foo(){
    var myControl = (MyControl)FindControl("my");
    myControl.Data.Prop1 = "some value";
    myControl.Data.Prop2 = 1234;
}
```

**How should I write my custom control's Data property ?**

By now, I have written this code  :

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    protected HiddenField inputInternalValue;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.inputInternalValue = new HiddenField();
        this.Controls.Add(this.inputInternalValue);
    }

    private void inputInternalValue_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputInternalValue.Value))
        {
            // use of Newtonsoft's Json convert
            m_Value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyControlValue>(inputInternalValue.Value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        inputInternalValue.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Value);

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MyControlValue
    {
        public string Prop1 {get; set;}
        public string Prop2 {get; set;}
        public static MyControlValue Default()
        {
            return new MyControlValue
            {
                Prop1 = "some default value",
                Prop2 = "999"
            };
        }
    }

    private MyControlValue m_Value;

    public MyControlValue Value
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            if (m_Value == null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputInternalValue.Value))
                {
                    // use of Newtonsoft's Json convert
                    m_Value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyControlValue>(
                        inputInternalValue.Value
                        );
                }
                else
                {
                    m_Value = MyControlValue.Default();
                }
            }
            return m_Value;
        }
    }        
}
```

However, this code is working as expected only at the first postback. If I add a button on the page, in which I try to read the values, the first postback the values will be kept, the second, not.

I think my issue is related to page lifecycle. I can't be sure the post back read has already been done.

Comment: I don't know if this is relavent but... On your `OnPreRender`. Where does `Value` come from?

Comment: It's a call to the `Value` property of the control.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Msdn's page: IPostBackDataHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx), I found a viable solution.

Instead of nesting my storage into a `<asp:hidden>` control, I manually wrote my postback handling.

Here is the result :

```
public class MyControl : Control
{

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        // other controls
    }

    public MyControlValue Value
    {
        get
        {
            var obj = ViewState["Value"];
            return (MyControlValue )(obj != null ? obj : ViewState["Value"] = MyControlValue .Default());
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Value"] = value;
        }
    } 

    public bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postCollection)
    {
        var presentValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Value);
        var postedValue = postCollection[postDataKey];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(presentValue) && !presentValue.Equals(postedValue))
        {
            Value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyControlValue>(postedValue);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
    {
        OnValueChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }


    #region Event

    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    protected virtual void OnValueChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValueChanged != null) ValueChanged(this, e);
    }

    #endregion Event

    [Serializable]
    public class MyControlValue
    {
        public string Prop1 {get; set;}
        public string Prop2 {get; set;}
        public static MyControlValue Default()
        {
            return new MyControlValue
            {
                Prop1 = "some default value",
                Prop2 = "999"
            };
        }
    }
}
```